# Python: list iteration only returns last value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn for GMM training and am trying to vary the number of mixture components by looping over a list of integers. But when I print my resulting models I only get the ones with 3 mixture components, or whatever I put as the last item in my list.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM

class_names = ['name1','name2','name3']
covs =  ['spherical', 'diagonal', 'tied', 'full']
num_comp = [1,2,3]

models = {}
for c in class_names:
    models[c] = dict((covar_type,GMM(n_components=num,
                covariance_type=covar_type, init_params='wmc',n_init=1, n_iter=10)) for covar_type in covs for num in num_comp)
print models
```

Can someone help please?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in the expression:

```
dict((covar_type,GMM(n_components=num,
                covariance_type=covar_type, init_params='wmc',n_init=1, n_iter=10)) for covar_type in covs for num in num_comp)
```

You are using the same `covar_type` as key over all iterations, thus rewriting the same element.

If we write the code in a more readable way, this is what it's happening:

```
data = dict()
for covar_type in covs:
    for num in num_comp:
        # covar_type is the same for all iterations of this loop
        # hence only the last one "survives"
        data[covar_type] = GMM(...)
```

If you want to keep all the values you should use a list of values instead of a single value *or* change the key.

For the list of values:

```
data = dict()
for covar_type in covs:
    data[covar_type] = values = []
    for num in num_comp:
        values.append(GMM(...))
```

For different keys:

```
data = dict()
for covar_type in covs:
    for num in num_comp:
        data[(covar_type, num)] = GMM(...)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I chose the last option. Is there a way to sort the output in a way that I first have all models for class_name 1, then all models for class_name 2, then all models for class_name 3? At the moment it's very messy and it's difficult to see through the results.

Comment: You should ask the question about sorting in a new post since it isn't related to your original post.

Comment: @user1372560 Please do *not* ask a question about that. Just search `python dict sorting` and you'll find tens of answer to your question. In particular: `dict`s are *not* sorted, if you want a sorted output you have to put the data into a list (`data = list(the_dict.items())`), afterwards you want to sort the data with a given `key`: `data.sort(key=...)`. In your case you could use `key=lambda item: (item[0][::-1], item[1])` which sorts all element first by number of components, then by `covar_type` and afterwards by value.