# Python:key error

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn for GMM training and am trying to vary the number of mixture components. I ran into problems, which were fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398242/python-list-iteration-only-returns-last-value).

I ended up with this code:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM

class_names = ['name1','name2','name3']
covs =  ['spherical', 'diagonal', 'tied', 'full']
num_comp = [1,2,3]
models = dict()

for c in class_names:
    for cov in covs:
        models[c,cov] = values = []
        for num in num_comp:
            values.append(GMM(n_components=num,covariance_type=cov, init_params='wmc',n_init=1, n_iter=10))
print models
```

I'm using the model dict() later on again and am running into problems because I don't know how to work with the dict.

```
training_data={'name1':'path2data1', 'name2': path2data2, 'name3': path2data3}

for cov in covs:
    for c in class_names:
        for num in num_comp:
            models[c][cov].fit(training_data[c])
```

I get the error "KeyError:'name1'"

I tried models[c,cov].fit(training_data[c]) as well but then I get the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fit'"

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you're assign value to dict by tuple (`c, cov` is equivalent to `(c, cov)`):

```
models[c,cov] = values = []
```

So, here you should access to dict values by tuple to:

```
for cov in covs:
    for c in class_names:
        for num in num_comp:
            models[(c, cov)].fit(training_data[c])
```

`AttributeError` throwing because you actually access to list: `models[(c,cov)]` is list that you created before (`values`)

**update for comment, try this:**

```
for c in class_names:
    models[c] = {}
    for cov in covs:
        models[c][cov] = values = []
        for num in num_comp:
            values.append(GMM(n_components=num,covariance_type=cov, init_params='wmc',n_init=1, n_iter=10))
```

but here you will get `list` in `models[c][cov]` anyway and should iterate it:

```
for cov in covs:
    for c in class_names:
        for num in num_comp:
            for f in models[c][cov]
                f.fit(training_data[c])
```

Comment: Mhm...still receiving the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fit'"

Comment: So are you saying I should access values instead? I don't understand, sorry

Comment: @user1372560 fit is function, right? And models[(c,cov)] is list. You trying to call fit function on list variable...

Comment: Yes, fit is a function. I had models as a {} before and  models[c][cov].fit(training_data[c]) worked. I don't really understand how the list thing works and how it's different. Your solution works for me but the problem is I have another function in my code that I have to use with the models list as well and I can't transfer the solution to my new problem...